# HWND deleting what is drawn on it; can't trace

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

So I have the following code:

```
void showBlankBitmap()
{

HDC hdcMem=CreateCompatibleDC(GetDC(printWind));
HBITMAP blankBimp=NULL;

    //create a black bitmap
    blankBimp=CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcMem, 1920, 1080);
    HBRUSH hBrushFill=CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0));
    HBITMAP hBmpOld=(HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, blankBimp);
    HBRUSH brushOld=(HBRUSH)SelectObject(hdcMem, hBrushFill);
    Rectangle(hdcMem, 0,0,1920, 1080);
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hBmpOld);
    SelectObject(hdcMem, brushOld);
    DeleteObject(hBrushFill);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
    SetBitmapDimensionEx(blankBimp, 1920, 1080, NULL);


    HDC hDC=GetDC(printWind);
    BitBlt(hDC, endOfLaptopW, 0, 1920, 1080, (HDC)blankBimp, 0, 0, NULL);
    DeleteDC(hDC);
}
```

And when I run it, it creates a black bitmap that covers the window which is what I want, but then it goes away. I have no idea what is deleting it. When walking through the program, I can see the window is still black after the function exits, but then since it is called in WndProc (message receiver) I can't track it after that, and the error seems to be happening either outside of wndProc or right when it returns. I have also tried SetBkColor. Doesn't work either. Help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the window got redrawn after that? For which message are you calling `showBlankBitmap`? `WM_PAINT`?

Comment: Among the errors, `CreateCompatibleDC(GetDC(printWind))` - um, The `HDC` returned from `GetDC()` should be released with `ReleaseDC()`; yours is being leaked. Worse, you don't seem to realize one `BitBlt`s from one `HDC` to another. that doesn't mean you just *cast* something that is NOT a `HDC` to one. A `HBITMAP` is not an `HDC` and that cast is wrong. The `BitBlt` should be done *from* the memory DC *to* the target DC. And from what this seems to be trying to do , nearly all of this isn't needed anyway.

Comment: One more bug, that hasn't been pointed out before: `blankBimp` is actually a monochrome bitmap, since you are creating a bitmap that is compatible with a **memory** device context (see [CreateCompatibleDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183489.aspx): *"When the memory DC is created, its display surface is exactly one monochrome pixel wide and one monochrome pixel high."*).

Answer (score 1):

This is to be expected. Windows do not maintain persistent drawing state. You need to handle the `WM_PAINT` message in your window's window procedure and do the painting then.

In the code you write:

```
hDC = GetDC(printWind);
```

When you are handling `WM_PAINT` you obtain the DC by calling `BeginPaint`. Call `EndPaint` when you've finished painting.

It goes like this:

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd &ps);
// ... paint onto hDC
EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```